# Can I say 没 to negate future events?

Tags: grammar, usage

I saw this sentence in a book:

> 明年这个时候你还没有毕业呢

I thought the sentence was wrong at first, but it says the sentence is grammatically correct and that there's nothing wrong with it. As you know, most Chinese grammar books tell you have to use 没 to negate past actions, so I didn't understand how 明年, which refers to a future time, can stand with 没. The book says 没(有) is used for unfinished events(毕业), regardless of the time.

Nevertheless, I'm still not sure what cases I have to use 没, not 不, with adverbials of future time like 明年, 下星期, etc. for. Can you give me some examples?

Also I'm wondering if there's a difference between the meanings of these two sentences:

> 明年这个时候你还**没有**毕业呢
>
> 明年这个时候你还**不**毕业呢

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In these two sentences, the difference is subtle. 你还没有 sounds more objective, and 你还不 sounds more subjective (so it would sound a little weird if "not yet graduate next year" is an objective fact – though still it's acceptable in loose conversations). I don't know whether this observation can be applied to other situations.

Comment: @Stan  When you say it sounds more subjective, do you mean that  你还不 would make it sound like "you will refuse to graduate next year," as if it is up to you?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty exactly.

Comment: @Stan Thanks for your reply. I'd like to ask one more question based on your observation. Please have a look at this dialogue: Question: 昨天他上班了没有? ~  Answer 1: 昨天他没上班 or Answer 2: 昨天他不上班. Does the first answer (没上班) just tell the objective fact that he didn't come to work yesterday and does the second one (不上班) mean that it's he himself who decided not to go to work? Also I'm wondering if those two answers are grammatically correct.

Comment: As 昨天 yesterday is not in future, the situation is a little different. Yes, Answer 1 still just tells the objective fact that he didn't come to work. But Answer 2 implies two things: (1) the fact that he didn't come to work; (2) he was on his holiday leave (or other valid reasons) so that he didn't have to come – and he decided not to come. Let's see another example: Q: 上周他去旅游了吗? A1: 上周他没去. A2: 上周他不去. Now A1 states the fact he didn't go. A2 implies "Last week was not the time he chose (or some other reasons), so he didn't go."

Comment: @Stan Thanks a lot for your answer. Can I ask one last question about 不? For the sentence 他不吸烟, 也不喝酒, can I assume that it implies these two things?: (1) the fact about his habit - he neither smokes nor drinks; (2) he's not going to smoke or drink for now, ahead of an important event, but he will smoke and drink later again.

Comment: @Jin You're welcome and please feel free to ask any more questions :) For 他不吸烟, 也不喝酒, (1) is true. However (2) is unknown because we can't predict one's choice in future for 100% sure – though the fact does imply he **possibly** won't smoke and drink in the future.

Comment: @Stan Then I'd like to wrap it up with one more example 他星期天不去图书馆. Based on your answers, I think the sentence means (1) fact: he never goes to the library on Sundays (but he may go on all days except Sunday); (2) description or prediction of his voluntary action: (2-1) if the 星期天 is a Sunday in the past, the sentence tells that he chose not to go to the library and he didn't go last Sunday; (2-2) if the 星期天 is this coming Sunday (or a particular Sunday that can be found from the context), the speaker predicts he's unlikely to go to the library that Sunday. Am I right?

Comment: @Jin The sentence is a little ambiguous. And you're right about the context is very important here. But, because if today is not Sunday, there always be a coming Sunday when hearing this sentence, and my first impression is "He doesn't plan to go to the library this Sunday." Yes, literally the logic conveyed by the sentence is OK for (1) the fact, but to clarify, we will emphasize it like "他**一般**星期天不去图书馆。" (generally) or "他星期天**从来不**去图书馆。" (never)

Comment: Also, "他星期天(是)不去图书馆的" works for "He would never go to the library on Sunday."

Comment: @Stan For "He didn't go to (=decided not to go to) the library last Sunday", is "他星期天不去图书馆" not enough and should I say "他上星期天不去图书馆" with 上(个) added before 星期天？ Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jin yes for the specific past time "last Sunday" you do have to add 上(个). But ... If "他上个星期天不去图书馆" is used to answer a question like "上个星期天他去图书馆了吗？", it sounds incomplete and would better be like "他上个星期天不去图书馆，去了电影院。" - anyway, that's his willingness and it's up to him, and the context is important.

Comment: @Stan Then, is "他上个星期天不去图书馆了" (with 了 added) a perfect, complete sentence? For your information, the reason why I asked this question is that I expected the 星期天 in the sentence 他星期天不去图书馆 could mean 'last Sunday' because I've often heard my Chinese friends mean 'last Sunday' by just 星期天 (literally just 'Sunday' in English) without any modifier in conversations. By the way I can move the comments exchanged between you and me to a chat, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Jin ok let's discuss it in a chat. Your observation is right but that's context related. If it's "他星期天没去图书馆" then the impression is "last Sunday".

Comment: @Stan Thank you so much for your help. If I have more questions, I'll move to the chat. :)

Comment: @Jin you're welcome and ... I missed this just now ... 他上个星期天不去图书馆了 implies he used to go to the library on Sunday but last Sunday he didn't go there - but it's not clear for the future. If you wanna say "since last Sunday he hasn't been to the library" then the time should be clarified as (从)上个星期天起.

Comment: ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂不（副）／没（副）［相同］都是副词表示否定，都可以修饰动词和某些形容词。以下情况可以互换：１。都可以用在动词前,但有一些不同：＂不＂否定的是事物的性质或人的主观愿望，＂没＂否定的是事物的变化、经历或者动作行为发生的客观事实：１他一句话也不说就走了。（否定＂说＂，从主观愿望说）２他一句话也没说就走了。（否定＂说了＂，从客观事实说）３他已经几天不来上课了。（强调主观上不愿意）４他已经几天没来上课了。（强调＂没有来＂这一客观事实）２。都可以用在一些有变化的形容词之前，但有一些不同：＂不＂否定事物具有某种性质或存在某种状态，＂没＂否定事物在性质状态发生变化：☐不圆 不熟 不红 不干 不着急 不紧张（没✓）１今天的月亮不圆。（不具有＂圆＂的性质）２今天的月亮没圆。（没有出现从＂不圆＂到＂圆＂的变化）３牛肉不熟，再煮一会儿。（不具有＂熟＂的状态）４牛肉没熟，再煮一会儿。（没有出现从＂不熟＂到＂熟＂的变化）５苹果还不红，不能摘！（没✓）６衣服还没干，再晒一会儿。（不✓）７我不着急，你满满说。（没✓）［不同］１用在动词性词语之前，＂不＂多否定将来的，未发生的动作行为，也可以否定经常性或习惯性，规律性的动作行为：＂没＂多否定过去的，已经发生的动作行为：１明天你们去吧，我不去。（将来，没✗）２我下周不参加考试。（将来，没✗）３他常常不吃早饭。（经常性，没✗）４这里从来不堵车。

Comment: （经常性，没✗）５昨天我感冒了，没去上课。（过去，不✗）６昨天晚上没下雨。（过去，不✗）。７我刚才没说话（过去，不✗）  to be continued

Comment: ２。在明确强调主观愿望的句子中，＂不＂也可以用于过去；在假设或表示估计的句子中＂没＂也可以用于将来：１昨天我是故意不告诉他的。（强调主观愿望，没✗）２我已经跟他谈过很多次，可他就是不同意。（强调主观愿望，没✗）３以前我不喝酒，现在经常喝。（强调主观愿望，没✗）４如果明天他还没回来，你就打电话告诉我。（假设，不✗）５要是天黑之前还没找到孩子，就报警吧！（假设，不✗）６明天这个时候，我还没下课呢。（估计，不✗）。７明天他还没回来呢，你后天再来吧。（估计，不✗）３。＂没＂可以与＂过＂配合，＂不＂不能；＂不＂可以和＂了＂配合，＂没＂不能：１我从来没见过他。（不✗）我没去过北京。（不✗）３别等了，玛丽不来了。（没✗）４小李今天不走了。（没✗）４。＂不＂可以用在性质形容词之前，＂没＂不能：☐不聪明 不漂亮 不舒服 不可爱 不真实 不复杂 不高 不矮 不长 不短 不近 不远 不快 不慢 （没✗）１她不聪明，但很努力。（没✗）２这几天我不舒服，在家休息。（没✗）３李明个子不高，比较胖。（没✗）５。＂不＂可以用在所有的助动词之前，＂没＂只能用在＂能、能够、敢＂等少数几个助动词前；＂不＂还可以用在＂是、像、等于、属于、知道＂等动词之前，＂没＂不能：☐不要 不会 不得 不肯 不愿意 不可以 不应该（没✗） 不能 不能够 不敢 （没✓）１昨天你不应该迟到。（没✗）２你不愿意帮我就酸了。（没✗）

Comment: ３这事我没敢告诉他。（不✓）☐不是 不像 不等于 不属于 不知道（没✗）１你长得不像你爸爸。（没✗）２他不姓张，他姓王。（没✗）３他不知道他的名字。（没✗）  3 comment spaces would have been sufficient, 4 used not to lose favorable mark for above second comment, ３个评论空间应该足够的，只是为了不丢失给第二个给予良好的分级就使用４个

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of 没 being restricted to past actions. It is perfectly useful, as in 范冰冰明年没有结婚的打算.

I interpret these sentences as:

明年这个时候你还没有毕业呢 = next year at this time you will still not have graduated.

明年这个时候你还不毕业呢 = next year at this time you will still refuse to graduate.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `還沒有` as `not yet`. It isn't limited to the past actions. It simply means `not yet`. Just like in English you can say `you will not yet have graduated next year`.

If it's just `沒`, most of the time it is used for the past actions.

I wouldn't say `明年這個時候你還不畢業呢`. But I would say `明年這個時候你還不畢業嗎` or `明年這個時候你還不畢業阿`. Both are questions.

Comment: you can only say "next year, you will not yet have graduated"

Answer (score 1):

Question: 昨天他上班了没有? ~ Answer 1: 昨天他没上班 or Answer 2: 昨天他不上班. 
Either answer is grammatically correct to the above question, but with different implications. Answer A implies that the fact that he goes to work did not happen yesterday, whereas Answer B implies that he was not on duty yesterday.

Comment: Excellent example, because it's realistic!

Answer (score 0):

Using 没 often suggests a of deviation from an expectation or likely scenario. It would have been plausible for us to graduate next year, but now it looks as if we will not achieve that.
However, if the action we failed to complete was entirely unexpected or even implausible, then 不 may feel more appropriate. But this will rarely be the case when you are also using 还, which emphasizes an implicit or explicit expectation.

Edit: 倪阔乐 just gave a good example of a negation that does not imply a failure to meet an expectation: *"Next year at this time you will still refuse to graduate."*
If you have been refusing to graduate all along, then a completion of the action　"to graduate" could not have been expected and 不 should be prefered over 没.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Anyway, in the sentence "明年这个时候你还没有毕业呢", "没有" means the person has not graduated right now. However, ["还" refers to the situation which the person is not graduated lasts into the future](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/86c717808762caaedd33d453.html). So "还没有" make sense of the future time "明天".

Q2:

> [“不”多用于主观叙述，可以否定现在、过去和将来的动作行为；“没”主要用于客观叙述，否定动作、状态的发生或完成，用于否定现在和过去，不能用于否定将来。](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/86c717808762caaedd33d453.html)

Translate into English:

"不" is used to negate present, past and future actions in subjective mostly.

"没" is used to negate present and past actions in objective mostly.

In this case, "you have not graduated next year(明年这个时候你还____毕业呢)" is objective description. So we should choose "没有". And "明年这个时候你还不毕业呢" is a incorrect sentence.

Answer (score 0):

### [没有] （ <=  ）  // past or now

For time：not happen, but may/might happen.

For things：not here, but was/should be somewhere.

### [还没有]      // for future

For time: not yet, but should will happen

For things：not here, but will be somewhere.

### [不]   （ ! ）     //any

reverse, could using everything and everywhere for everyone

$不不 is Yes

$不 is no

---

## When you want to check graduate

sometimes, We should careful the time point (明年)in the conversation. 
future：at this case, we use 还没有。when we say it, we may ignore 还，so we may say 没有 instead of 还没有. becasue we know the time is next year. But the meaning is not equal to 没有 if there is no 明年（future time point）

没有毕业 ：

还没有毕业：

明年没有：=> 明年（还）没有

不毕业：

明年这个时候你还没有毕业呢
// will graduate

```
If (time < graduateTime)
     Return “没有”
```

明年这个时候你还不毕业呢
// no graduate

```
If (time != graduateTime)
       Return "不"
```

This is my first answer in stackoverflowers.
Thanks！hope you understand